# creating new queue using torque/PBS "access from host not allowed"

Tags: pbs, torque, fastq

I have carried out the following commands.

```
qmgr -c "create queue fastq queue_type=execution" 
qmgr -c "set queue fastq started=true" 
qmgr -c "set queue fastq enabled=true" 
qmgr -c "set queue fastq acl_hosts=compute-0-30" 
qmgr -c "set queue fastq acl_host_enable=true" 
qmgr -c "set queue fastq acl_users=username" 
qmgr -c "set queue fastq acl_user_enable=true"
```

But when I have the following header for my PBS script,

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -N job
#PBS -u username
#PBS -q fastq
#PBS -be

mpirun script
```

I get the following error:

```
host.edu > qsub runscript
qsub: Access from host not allowed, or unknown host MSG=host ACL rejected the submitting     host: user username@email.com, queue fastq, host host.edu
```

Comment: Can you add your full qmgr -c 'p s' output?

Answer (score 2):

If you are submitting the job from a computer that is not the torque server, you will also need to set the `submit_hosts` flag.

See Appendix B in the documentation:

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/12-appendices/serverParameters.htm#submist_hosts

Take special care to use the full hostname of the machine ( the value returned from `uname -n`).

You should always use the fully qualified hostname as torque can be quite picky.

---

I would also recommend that you take a look at `torque.setup` inside the root directory of the tar ball. It will seed a basic configuration.

```
qmgr -c 'p s' 
create queue batch
set queue batch queue_type = Execution
set queue batch resources_default.nodes = 1
set queue batch resources_default.walltime = 01:00:00
set queue batch enabled = True
set queue batch started = True
#
# Set server attributes.
#
set server scheduling = True
set server acl_hosts = foo.edu
set server default_queue = batch
set server log_events = 511
set server mail_from = adm
set server scheduler_iteration = 600
set server node_check_rate = 150
set server tcp_timeout = 300
set server job_stat_rate = 45
set server poll_jobs = True
set server mom_job_sync = True
set server keep_completed = 300
set server next_job_number = 19193
set server moab_array_compatible = True
```